# Azure IoT Hub - Send message (C2D) to one device on 2 topics instead of devicebound/#

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub

As a MQTT client (device), I am using `devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/#` topic to receive Cloud to Device messages. This device is a gateway for me and there are 3 devices attached to it.
I want to send 3 different commands to 1 gateway on 3 different topics, like

```
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/device1
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/device2
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/device3
```

My gateway is registered in iot-hub and I use it at `{deviceid}`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official document "[Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support)", it says:

> Since IoT Hub is not a general purpose pub-sub messaging broker, it
>   only supports the documented topic names and topic filters.
>
> IoT Hub delivers messages with the Topic Name
>   devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/, or
>   devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/{property_bag} if there are
>   any message properties.

Here is a solution using system property "messageId" as the filter. So your three topics:

```
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/device1 
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/device2 
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/device3
```

would look like this:

```
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/%24.mid=device1&%24.to=%2Fdevices%2Ftest1%2Fmessages%2FdeviceBound&iothub-ack=full
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/%24.mid=device2&%24.to=%2Fdevices%2Ftest1%2Fmessages%2FdeviceBound&iothub-ack=full
devices/{deviceid}/messages/devicebound/%24.mid=device3&%24.to=%2Fdevices%2Ftest1%2Fmessages%2FdeviceBound&iothub-ack=full
```

This is the test:

Send C2D message from azure device explorer:

[image]

Receive C2D message from MQTTBox:

[image]